# CQWP, CommonViewFields, column with swedish special characters does not go to xsl

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

I have a CQWP that i want to use to rollup list information from som sub sites, the lists contains columns that are named with Swedish characters: Å, Ä, and Ö.

Have in mind also that I am doing this on SharePoint Online in Office 365 so I cant redefine my internal name, I need my customer to be able to define swedish characters while I am still able to roll them up using CQWP. So to define all SiteColumns in code or such solutions will not help.

So, now when I try to style the CQWP with ItemStyle.xsl I dont get these columns sent. My CommonViewFields is defined as follows:

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Positivt,Note;Negativt,Note;Projekt,TaxonomyFieldMulti;Veckonummer,Choice;M_x00e5_nad,Choice</property>
```

All other properties in the web part definition file are left as is.

The columns, Positivt, Negativt, Projekt and Veckonummer get sent as expected, but I never receive the column M_x00e5_nad which has the displayname Månad. I also have some more fieldnames that use swedish characters, but this is a good example. Any suggestions?

Best regards
/Richard

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, albeit in MOSS so not sure if it will solve your issue, which I resolved by using the field guid in  `CommonViewFields` and then renamed the field in the `DataColumnRenames` property.

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">447493f6-8639-4683-940f-3438d1893f97,Lookup</property>
<property name="DataColumnRenames" type="string">{447493f6-8639-4683-940f-3438d1893f97},MyFieldName</property>
```

I had to enter the guid in `CommonViewFields` without braces and in `DataColumnRenames` with them.